# storing data after scraping and parsing

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have an html file which I have parsed using Beautiful Soup 4 and this is the section I am interested in

```
[
 <td>Name :</td>,   <td>xyz</td>, 
 <td>Mobile :</td>, <td>180-14587962</td>, 
 <td>Company:</td>, <td>abc Comp</td>, 
 <td>Name :</td>,   <td>  </td>, 
 <td>Mobile :</td>, <td>  </td>, 
 <td>Company:</td>, <td>  </td>, 
 <td>Name :</td>,   <td>  </td>, 
 <td>Mobile :</td>, <td>  </td> 
]
```

I just need to extract Name and Mobile separately (they are on same level in the parse tree). How do I go about this? I have alreadty tried using [soup.find_next_siblings method](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling) but unable to store the data in the desired format (Two separate lists for Number and Mobile )

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """
 <td>Name :</td>,   <td>xyz</td>, 
 <td>Mobile :</td>, <td>180-14587962</td>, 
 <td>Company:</td>, <td>abc Comp</td>, 
 <td>Name :</td>,   <td>  </td>, 
 <td>Mobile :</td>, <td>  </td>, 
 <td>Company:</td>, <td>  </td>, 
 <td>Name :</td>,   <td>  </td>, 
 <td>Mobile :</td>, <td>  </td> 
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
x = soup.find_all("td")
print x[1]
print x[3]
```

---

**stdout**

```
<td>xyz</td>
<td>180-14587962</td>
```

---

**DEMO**

http://ideone.com/xDzeni

Comment: The thing is this structure is repetitive and not ends here. So I will get only first pair according to your answer and not the remaining ones.

Comment: You need to use a regex to get all matches. Can you post a more complete sample ?

Comment: the structure keeps on repeating with 3 td tags (Name Mobile Company)... That's it

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it

```
for tag in soup.findAll('td'):
  if tag.text.strip("\n").strip(' ').strip("\n")== 'Name :':
      inter=tag.find_next_sibling()
      list_name.append(inter.text.strip("\n").strip(' ').strip("\n"))
  if tag.text.strip("\n").strip(' ').strip("\n")== 'Mobile :':
      inter=tag.find_next_sibling()
      list_mobile.append(inter.text.strip("\n").strip(' ').strip("\n"))
```

Looped through all td tags to find 'Name :' or 'Mobile :' and added the next tag (which contains the value) to separate lists